# Importing dto class in Nest JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

[image]I'm trying to use a DTO to define my data for my controller within Nest.js.

I am following the [tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)

I have created my DTO within `src/controllers/cats/dto/create-cat.dto.js`

```
export class CreateCatDto {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly age: number;
  readonly breed: string;
}
```

I am confused as to how this gets imported into the application though. The documentation doesn't actually state that it needs to be imported so I assumed nest is doing some magic behind the scenes? All though I have a feeling this isn't the case.

I am trying to import it directly in my controller:

```
import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';
```

But this throws an error:

```
Unexpected token (2:11)
  1 | export class CreateCatDto {
> 2 |   readonly name: string;
    |            ^
  3 |   readonly age: number;
  4 |   readonly breed: string;
  5 | }
```

The DTO code is ripped directly off the nest docs so there shouldn't be an ussue with the code (all though `readonly name: string;` doesn't look like javascript I have come across before).

For reference, here is the rest of my cat Controller where I am trying to use the DTO

```
import { Controller, Bind, Get, Post, Body, Res, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
// import { CreateCatDto } from './dto/create-cat.dto';

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {

  @Post()
    @Bind(Res(), Body())
    async create(res, body, createCatDto) {
        console.log("createCatDto", createCatDto)
        res.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).send();
    }

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Does the DTO class need to be imported and then use bind to my create function like `Res()` and `Body()` or does nest do some magic behind the scene since they never state to import it in there docs?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not javascript, it's TypeScript. You created JS file - src/controllers/cats/dto/create-cat.dto.js

Comment: That's confusing because in their docs, they clearly recommend using es6 over typescript as you can see in the screenshot I have added and can be found here https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers under the header `POST handler`

Comment: cool fact is that all the docs have typescript/javascript code examples, so they gave both examples.

Comment: @MatheusSilva not all, JS contains in some cases TS

Comment: I am aware of that, but in this particular example, the code snippet is exactly the same fort JS and TS. And as the screenshot states: "we recommend using classes here" so I assumed they are both JS snippets...

Comment: So what would be the JS equivalent for creating a DTO in nest?

Comment: you found a bug in their docs!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quick Answer:** You can't use DTO in JavaScript ES6

**Not So Long Answer:** Here is an excerpt from the docs, just has DTO was introduced.

> Firstly, we need to establish the DTO (Data Transfer Object) schema. A
>   DTO is an object that defines how the data will be sent over the
>   network. We could do this by using TypeScript interfaces, or by simple
>   classes.

As you can see, it was used there as an **interface** to provide **Static typing**. You really can't utilize DTOs in JS because **interface** and **Static typing** are not part of ES6 standards.

You should skip the DTO part for ES6 and use the `@Body()` argument like this instead

```js
@Post()
@Bind(Body())
async create(createCatDto) {
    // TODO: Add some logic here
}
```

**My Advice:** Try considering moving to Typescript to take full advantage of NestJS.